# ignore table prefixes while code generation in Hibernate perspective

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jboss-tools

I am using JBoss Hibernate Perspective to generate JPA Entities. 
But all my tables begin with tbl_ prefix.

I am migrating codes from PHP YII to Java and in YII model generator have an option to specify prefix and then the models that are generated don't have "tbl" prefix.

How can we achieve same with Eclipse and Hibernate perspective since as of now , all classes are being generated with Tbl Prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to do it is specify table attribute in your configuration:

```
<class name="User" table="tbl_user" />
```

If you are using annotation:

```
@Table(name = "tbl_user")
public class User
```

By default we keep name of POJO same as table name. If you don't prefer naming scheme by hibernate, you can change default behavior  by extending [ImprovedNamingStrategy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/cfg/ImprovedNamingStrategy.html). As you can see [ImprovedNamingStrategy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/cfg/ImprovedNamingStrategy.html) implements [NamingStrategy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/NamingStrategy.html).

eg:-

```
    public class CustomImprovedNamingStrategy extends ImprovedNamingStrategy
{
    @Override
    public String columnName(String columnName)
    {
        return columnName;
    }

    @Override
    public String tableName(String tableName)
    {
        return tableName.replace("tbl_","");
    }
}
```

CustomImpovedNamingStrategy shall be set while creating SessionFactory:-

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
    .setNamingStrategy(ImprovedNamingStrategy.INSTANCE)
    .addFile("Item.hbm.xml")
    .addFile("Bid.hbm.xml")
    .buildSessionFactory();
```

refer: [Implementing Naming Strategy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-namingstrategy).

PS: In similar way [DefaultNamingStrategy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/cfg/DefaultNamingStrategy.html) can be used to modify Hibernate's default naming strategy.

Comment: thanks, I used DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy to achieve same result  passing the strategy to Hibernate perspective in Eclipse. However once I added hibernate-tools-4.3.1.CR1 to pom.xml , mvn jetty:run started giving "timeout while scanning annotations" and I had to add also a java argument for waitTime to 2 minutes. My build run time increased 3 times and also application started taking memory from 130 MB to 200MB for booting..

Comment: I was thinking to add this as an Ant task , but after these issues removed pom dependencies once generated models. Have you also encountered similar issues ?

Comment: Haven't used 'DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy', so can't really comment.